# Summarise monthly (seasonal) factors from an ts(rnorm) object

Tags: r, time-series, dplyr, summary

I am trying to make a monthly factor variable with the dplyr and ts packages.

This means:

1. Take the average of the months over Y years
2. Sum all the ^1s (twelve, one for each month)
3. Divide 1 by 2 for each month <- this is your factor for that month.

So, if each month got it's numeric value, March's factor would be

> 3/sum(1:12)
>   [1] 0.03846154

or 3.8%.

I feel like this should be pretty straight forward, but I am messing things up and can't tell why (maybe it's mid-terms):

```
x <- ts(matrix(rnorm(300,100,3)), start = c(1961,1), frequency = 12) y 
y <- x  %>% summarise(month_factor = for (i in z) mean(i)) 
Error in UseMethod("summarise_") :    no applicable method for 'summarise_' applied to an object of class "ts"
```

I am aware this first effort is pretty substandard, but I am bumping into the compounding issue of not being able to use `mutate` because the months are the columns in the ts object `x` I build above.

Comment: Try making it a matrix.

Comment: No shaming intended. It took me several minutes to get around to that solution the first time I encountered a similar problem.

Comment: What's the protocol on these questions - delete?

Comment: If you have a solution that you can exemplify in code, you can search to see if it comes up easily, and if not then post your own answer and after a suitable interval (a couple of hours I think), you can checkmark it. I did a search to see if I could find the answer I remembered posting but couldn't find it. Maybe it was one of my answers on rhelp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
x <- ts(matrix(rnorm(300,100,3)), start = c(1961,1), frequency = 12)
```

As suggested by BondedDust, you can convert `x` to a matrix:

```
m <- matrix(data = as.numeric(x), ncol = 12, byrow = TRUE)
```

Adjust by seasonal average:

```
m = m/matrix(colMeans(m, na.rm = TRUE), ncol = 12, nrow=nrow(m), byrow = TRUE)
```

convert back to `ts`:

```
y = ts(data = as.numeric(m), start = start(x), frequency = 12)
```

Comment: @Pascal See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments